# Find sum of $ar^0 + ar^1 + ar^2 + \dotsm + ar^n$

Tags: induction, geometric-progressions

I am trying to deduce the formula of sum of $n$ terms of a GP in a way not described in the book and hence after taking $a$ as common factor, we are left behind with $r^0 + r + r^2 + r^3$ ( I took $n = 4$ ). I am stuck so as to how to find the sum of $r^0 + r + r^2 + r^3$ for any value of $n$. Is there any formula to find the sum of the series $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i$ ?

Comment: Yes.... there is a very well known one and an easy one to deduce.

Comment: What is the way described in your book?

Comment: "I am trying to deduce the formula of sum of n terms of a GP in a way not described in the book"  What book?  And what way do the they describe it?....  But I'm confused.  How on earth can you possibly know the the words "geometric progression" mean, and know that the sum $r^0 + r + r^2 + r^3$  is referred to as a "geometric progression" but *not* know the well known formula for this?  I've never seen *any* seen any text define what a geometric progression is and *not* give the formula.

Comment: "how to find the sum of $r^0 + r + r^2 + r^3$ for any value of $n$".  $r^0 + r + r^2 + r^3$ does not depend on $n$.

Comment: @fleablood I have the formula for GP sum, I asked for a formula of r^0 + ... + r^n for any n

Comment: @fleablood I actually wanted the proof also, which is not in the book.

Comment: " I have the formula for GP sum" and it is?

Comment: @fleablood https://images.app.goo.gl/JynfYmQ9ETTA6W6m9 this one. That's all I've got. No proof, nothing.

Comment: Okay.... I'm sorry but *WHAT* is your question?  It is not in the *least* bit clear what you are asking or where you are having trouble.  The formula (if $r\ne 1$) is $(1+r+ ..... +r^n) =\frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ and the proof is:  $(1-r)(1+r+....+r^n)=1-r^{n+1}$

Comment: @fleablood your answer is perfect. Thanks. I got what I wanted.

Comment: What is the way described in the book?

Comment: @user https://images.app.goo.gl/JynfYmQ9ETTA6W6m9 just this formula

Comment: Ok, this is not a derivation. This is just a formula.

Comment: It should be remarked that you use the symbol $n$ inconsistently. Obviously in one of your examples you assume that the last term is $ar^{n-1}$. The same assumption is used in the formula you cite.

Comment: @user I was of the impression that the last erm _is_  always $ar^n-1$

Comment: But in your question it is $ar^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $(1 + r + r^2 + .........  + r^n)(1-r) = $

$1\times (1 + r + r^2 + .........  + r^n) - r\times(1 + r + r^2 + .........  + r^n)=$

$(1 + r + r^2 + .........  + r^n)-(r + r^2 + r^3........  + r^{n+1})=$

$1 + (r+ r^2 + ...... + r^n) -(r+r^2 +..... + r^n) - r^{n+1}=$

$1 - r^{n+1}$

Then so long as $r \ne 1$ we have $(1 + r+ r^2 + ..... + r^n) = \frac {1-r^n}{1-r}$.

And if $r$ *does* equal $1$ we have $1 + r + .... + r^n = 1+1+..... + 1 = n+1$.